# Regarding Google Places Near by Search

Tags: google-places-api, google-places

While searching for places using google nearby search for anyone of  type from ["hospital", "pharmacy", "doctor", "dentist", "physiotherapist", "clinic", "diagnostic center"] ,  In return, the response from Google Places is giving  places other than the mentioned types. Any solution to avoid results other than mentioned types.  The e.g. parameters   {    location: [ '6.4504948', '3.3956989' ],   type: 'Clinics',   radius: 25000  }